# Change connection string in Entity Framework from localDB to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use SQL Server 2016 instead of localdb. When I try to change it in the web.config file from `mssqllocaldb` to `v13.0`
it gives me the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
> occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
> not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
> correct and that SQL

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server 2016 did you install? And did you specify an instance name during installation? The SQL Server 2016 **Express** is by default installed as `.\SQLEXPRESS`, while other editions are typically installed as *default, unnamed* instances (which you can access using `.` or `(local)` as your server/instance name)

Comment: Enterprise edition and didn't specify anything

Comment: So then your connection string should be something like `Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=(your db name); Integrated Security=SSPI;` or something like that - can you please show us (by editing/updating your question) what you're using??

Comment: "What is wrong with this connection string I'm not showing"?

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the configuration at [MSDN: Entity Framework Config File Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx)

An example *web.config* could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MySqlServerInstance;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```